# Get childscope element from rootscope

Tags: jquery, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to do something that looks basic but I am not able to do it.

In have a simple directive

```
app.directive('mainContent', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        content: "="
    },
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
}
})
```

and a main page with a simple script

```
<main-content content="content"></main-content>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?Admin") > -1) {
    $('.editable').attr('contenteditable','true');
}
});
</script>
```

The directive load the following content pages/home.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center editable">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

I suppose my script is unable to add contenteditable="true" attribute because the directive is creating a childscope.

How can I do this without ading my script in the pages/home.html ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to do anything with scopes really, it's just that Angular is going over the HTML once it's loaded to do its magic, and you're also doing JQuery code on `document.ready` as well.

So, what catches first ?

Probably JQuery is unable to find your code since Angular hasn't rendered the directive yet and the HTML isn't loaded.

I suggest 2 things:

1. Don't use JQuery when you're using Angular.
2. If you really must or this is just an exercise of some sort, you can wrap it in a `setTimeout` which makes the code wait and execute once everything is finished.

   ```
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('.editable').attr('contenteditable','true');
   }, 0);
   ```

Edit: You can do it in the link function of the directive, like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    $('.editable').attr('contenteditable','true');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/HB7LU/13102/) is updated.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Instead of using JQuery what do you suggest to add the attribute?

Comment: @Artefact I'm sorry, I attached the wrong fiddler by mistake. It's updated now. It does work with a timeout 0 since it's not the time that matters, it's the mechanism that pushes the search till the end of the queue. You can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: @Artefact And regarding the attribute - it's a rule of thumb that DOM manipulations should be done in directives, so I would suggest doing that in the link function of the directive. I'm updating the fiddler to show how.

Comment: Many thanks for explanation and help. That's clear for me now!